# Is SED trying to pull a fast one on moi(backreference problem)?

Tags: sed, regular-expression, gnu

I'm trying to pull out the **third** subexpression from this line:

```
#EXTRA_GROUPS="dialout cdrom floppy audio video plugdev users"
```

(yep, the `adduser.conf` file, for those of you who are curious) with:

```
sed 's/\(EXTRA_GROUPS=\)\("\)\(.*\)\("\)/\3/' adduser.conf
```

While this does work and produces

```
#dialout cdrom floppy audio video plugdev users
```

(I've left the `#` symbol out of the expression, so please disregard), this

```
sed 's/\(EXTRA_GROUPS=\)\("\)\(.*\)\("\)//3' adduser.conf
```

doesn't and leaves the file as is.

I do realize that the last example is supposed to delete back reference number three, but when I modify the command with `/sd/3` ("replace 3rd subexpression with `sd`") it doesn't really do anything, either.

I have tried running the command with the `-n //p` options-all to the same result.

I'm using GNU `sed` version 4.2.2 on a Debian Jessie box.

Have I missed some crucial part of my core utilities "education" or is it that I haven't been out in the sun for while?

Comment: `s/.../.../3` means "replace 3rd **occurrence**" (of the entire pattern), not "replace 3rd **subexpression**".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `/n` *flag* to the substitute command `s` in `sed` does not have anything to do with the *back-reference* `\n`.

- With, e.g., `s/regex/string/3` you replace the third match of `regex` (on the current line) with `string`.
- With `s/regex/\3/`, you replace the first match of `regex` with the third capture-group.
- With `s/regex/\3/3`, you replace the third match of `regex` with the third capture-group.

In this case, I would probably go with something simpler, like

```
sed 's/^.*EXTRA_GROUPS="\([^"]*\)".*$/\1/'
```

There's no use in capturing bits of the string if you're not using it.

Comment: To clarify, I was referring to the `sed -n 's///p' filename`(print only the modified line) command. But in any case-killer! That answers my question! I was also curious if I can replace the third regex with some new string, in this case everything inside the double quotes "dialout, cdrom, floppy..." with, say "foobar"?

Comment: @Kusalananda: Since you have `.*` at the beginning and at the end of the pattern, you can leave out the `^` and `$`, because greedy `*` will eat up everything to the bounds of the line anyhow. As well, you can replace `[^"]` with `.`, as long as behaviour for additional double quotes is undefined.